# How do you select a URL in Safari and open it

Tags: safari

In Safari you can select an area and right-click gives a menu including an option to search for it.

However if the region was a URL I would like to open it directly. How can this be done?

the URL is not a link just `https://www.example.com`

I just tried this in editing the question and just saw the search, on preview (and I expect just reading the answer) I got 3 goto address options on the top of the menu. On GitHub I never get these goto address options even when just reading.